# MarketingCloudSDK - iOS SDK XCFramework support

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, ios, mobilepush-ios

As Apple has officially noted that fat binaries are an incorrect distribution means for Universal framework support and have released XCFrameworks as a proper solution to this issue, they have also iteratively released updates to Xcode noting an urgency in supporting/migrating all 3rd party frameworks to either XCFrameworks or SPM. Salesforce seems to be the last dependency used by our company's product that hasn't seemed to update for this requirement at this time. What is the current roadmap for supporting either XCFrameworks or SPM and complying to Apple's requirements. Note that this will be required for proper development on Apple Silicon as well.

Edit: this is designated as the primary support interface through GitHub, but it honestly looks like no one actively upkeeps with replies here. Just another reason to drop the product all together...

Answer (score 2):

We just happen to have the very same issue, where Salesforce is our last dependency pending to be migrated to XCFramework.

I posted a similar question a while ago (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/331731/apple-silicon-support-for-ios-marketingcloudsdk?noredirect=1#comment490312_331731), but it seems to be deleted.

@BillMote any news about this?

Comment: This is honestly quite mind boggling due to the size and nature of Salesforce. I know their framework is fairly immature, but this is pretty ridiculous. Especially with the fact they don’t reveal any product roadmaps. Deleting a question as well before a resolution is in bad taste too..